# Angularjs. Error: $controller:ctrlreg A controller with this name is not registered

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting the following error on the chrome console:

The controller with the name 'registerCtrl' is not registered.

for some reason, my registerCtrl is not being recognized when routing to the root or /register.

for some reason, my registerCtrl is not being recognized when routing to the root or /register.

**Index.html**

```
<html ng-app="testApp">
 <head>
  <base href="/">
  <title></title>
  <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app/app.js"></script>
  <script src="app/register/registerCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="app/adminDashBoard/adminDashBoardCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="app/services/hubProxy.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app/directives/alerts/alertDir.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div ng-view></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**app.js(boostrap)**

```
(function () {
     var app = angular.module('testApp', ["ngRoute"]);

 app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
     .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "/app/register/register.html",
            controller: 'registerCtrl'
     })
    .when("/register", {
        templateUrl: "/app/register/register.html",
        controller: 'registerCtrl'
    })
    .when("/adminDashBoard", {
            templateUrl: "/app/adminDashBoard/adminDashBoard.html",
            controller:'adminDashboardCtrl'
    })
});
})();
```

**registerCtrl**

```
(function () {

var registerController = function ($scope, hubProxy) {
    var hub = hubProxy("", "UserRegisterHub");

    $scope.registerUser = function () {
        // call hub and pass these details
        if ($scope.userName !== "" && $scope.emailAddress !== "") {
            hub.invoke("RegisterUser", function (result) {
                // confirm user use boostrap alert
                $scope.showAlert = true;
            });
        }
    }
    $scope.userName = "yoyoy";
    $scope.email = "";
};

angular.module("testApp").controller('RegisterCtrl', registerController);

})();
```

**register.Html**

```
<div>
<a ng-href="adminDashBoard">Admin Dashboard</a>
<alert showAlert="true"></alert>
<label>{{userName}}</label>
<form name="register">
    <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" required="" ng-model="userName" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" required="" ng-model="email" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" ng-click="registerUser()" value="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Any ideas?  thanks

Comment: Are you sure this path is right?

Comment: @Canet, Yes.. root/app